# Saving arrayBuffer as an image in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, image

I am receiving image as an `arraybuffer` via `axios` and trying to convert it to `nodebuffer` and save it using `fs` naturally. Now this code, show down below, executes without producing an error, however saved .jpg file wont open and when i try to get more info about it through ubuntu terminal I get that it's `main.jpg: JPEG 2000 Part 1 (JP2)`. Here is the code

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data);
fs.writeFile('main.jpg', buffer, 'binary', err => {

      if (err) console.log('file system', err);
      else console.log('done');
});
```

where `reponse.data` is said arraybuffer

@Marc
callForMedia() gets the image, response.data contains actual image data

```
this.callForMedia(arr[0].url, true)
.then(response => {

      fs.writeFile('main.jpg', response.data, err => {

          if (err) console.log('file system', err);
          else {
               fs.readFile('main.jpg', (err, res) => {

                       console.log(res === response.data);
               });
          }
      });
})
```

`console.log()` outputs `false`

Comment: what does `response.data` looks like ?

Comment: @Marc looks like `<Buffer 00 00 00 0c 6a 50 20 20 0d 0a 87 0a 00 00 00 14 66 74 79 70 6a 70 32 20 00 00 00 00 6a 70 32 20 00 00 00 2d 6a 70 32 68 ...`, I also tried setting `axios` `response-type` header to `stream` and implementing [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/download-files-images-with-axios-in-node-js) solution to no avail...

Comment: Is the buffer a valid jpg image ? if so there is no need for you the create a new buffer from the response data. just write `response.data` to the fs. Try to load the image from the fs with `fs.readFile(...)` and compare the buffers to see if you get the image binary correct.

Comment: @Marc I updated question w/ code

Comment: No, i mean you should save the image on your fs (download it manual) and read it again with node, and then compare the buffers you get from `response.data` and that manual file you downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `'binary'` argument:

```js
fs.writeFile('main.jpg', buffer, err => { ... });
```

Per [the Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), this is a way of converting text to binary data, and should not be used when writing buffers directly:

> 'binary': Alias for 'latin1'. See binary strings for more background on this topic. The name of this encoding can be very misleading, as all of the encodings listed here convert between strings and binary data. For converting between strings and Buffers, typically 'utf-8' is the right choice.

As for why `res !== response.data`, it's because they're two different objects, and in fact two different types of objects. To compare their actual contents, you need to use [`Buffer.compare()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_compare_buf1_buf2) and convert the `ArrayBuffer` to a `Buffer`:

```js
console.log(Buffer.compare(res, Buffer.from(response.data)) === 0);
```

Comment: removed 'binary' argument, still getting the same result, invalid image ... do you suggest trying `fs.writeFile('main.jpg', response.data, err => { ... })` where `response.data` is `ArrayBuffer` or rather `fs.writeFile('main.jpg', Buffer.from(response.data),err => { ... })` ?

Comment: The latter. fs.writeFile does not accept ArrayBuffers.